# array in jquery not populating

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

all,

I have an array that does not seem to get populated.  I can see that the length of my array but can't seem to view the data with a simple alert.

My function is called when I click on an href:

I then look for elements that have a class of .jobRole to populate my array and to be displayed with alert.  However I'm having difficulties.  Thanks for any assistance.

```
function close() {

    var jobRoleArray = [];

    $(".jobRole").each(function (index) {

        var jobRoleIndex = index;
        var jobRoleID = $(this).attr('id');
        var jobRoleName = $(this).text();

        var roleInfo = {
            "roleIndex": jobRoleIndex,
            "roleID": jobRoleID,
            "roleName": jobRoleName
        };

        queryStr = { "roleInfo": roleInfo };
        jobRoleArray.push(queryStr);

    });

    alert('show length: ' + jobRoleArray.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < jobRoleArray.length; i++) {

        alert('jobRoleIndex: ' + jobRoleArray[i].roleInfo.jobRoleIndex +
                ' jobRoleID: ' + jobRoleArray[i].roleInfo.jobRoleID +
                ' jobRoleName: ' + jobRoleArray[i].roleInfo.jobRoleName +
                ' showCount: ' + i);

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you see in the alerts? Any errors in the console?

Comment: You're trying to access the name of the data you put in originally, not the map keys under which the data resides.

Comment: It doesn't solve your problem (Dennis has that covered), but you should probably check out the `map` function, which lets you transform jQuery objects into arrays: `var jobRoleArray = $(".jobRole").map(function(jobRole, index) { var jobRoleIndex = index; var jobRoleID = jobRole.attr("id"); ... return queryStr; });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't accessing the correct properties; use this instead:

```
alert('jobRoleIndex: ' + jobRoleArray[i].roleInfo.roleIndex +
        ' jobRoleID: ' + jobRoleArray[i].roleInfo.roleID +
        ' jobRoleName: ' + jobRoleArray[i].roleInfo.roleName +
        ' showCount: ' + i);
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked.  Really had some sleepy eyes and didn't catch this.  Thanks again!